# mysql total working hours

Tags: php, mysql

```
id     title                              start                    end
1   Doing Coding for this project.  2013-04-02 02:00:00     2013-04-02 04:00:00
2   Doing Coding for this project.  2013-04-02 04:00:00     2013-04-02 06:00:00
3   Doing Coding for this project.  2013-04-02 06:00:00     2013-04-02 06:30:00
```

I have above `MySQL` database table record. Now i want to get the total number of `hours.`

I am developing `TimeSheet Management Application` and **we need to display total working hours with minutes and second of employee. (i.e 04:30:00 according to data i share)**

**what i have tried?**

`SELECT HOUR(TIMEDIFF(end,start)) AS 'totalHour'` but works only for each row not on all records.

I have also tried `TIMESTAMPDIFF`.

Is this possible?

**EDIT**

From the answer i have received from people i have tried every single of them but everytime i just get `4` or `4.5000` but it should return `06:30:00`.

Comment: did you tried `SUM(..)`?

Comment: @Akam thanx for reply but i don't think it will give me `SUBTRACTED` return.

Comment: you can try it and see the real result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this query

```
SELECT
 id, 
 title, 
 TIME_FORMAT(SEC_TO_TIME(sum(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF( end, start)))), "%h:%i") AS diff
FROM 
 tbl1
GROUP BY  
 title
```

According to the data that you have given answer should be 4:30. Pl cross check in you records.

**[FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/260ca/15)**

Answer (score 4):

The range of [`HOUR()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_hour) function is `0 to 23` so it's not correct to use it for total hours in diff.

For single value you could use [`TIMESTAMPDIFF()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff) like:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, start, end) AS `totalHour` FROM ...
```

If you want to calculate it for whole project, you have to sum up all time differences and them print it formatted probably with funciton like [`TIME_FORMAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_time-format) which prints hour larger than 24:

> > > If the time value contains an hour part that is greater than 23, the %H and %k hour format specifiers produce a value larger than the usual range of 0..23. The other hour format specifiers produce the hour value modulo 12.

So you can use:

```
 SELECT TIME_FORMAT( SEC_TO_TIME( SUM( TIME_TO_SEC(end) - TIME_TO_SEC(start))), "%H")
            AS `totalHour`
 FROM ...
 GROUP BY sort_of_project_id
```

If you need seconds/minutes too (as suggested in comment), use either:

- `time_to_sec( <left side of select>)/3600`  which will return value like `4.84 hours`
- `TIME_FORMAT( ..., "%H:%m:%s")` which will display `4:38:24`

Comment: i am getting o4 everytime...but it should return 06:30:00

Comment: i have tried your suggested query...i have user_id for group so i just replace `sort_of_project_id` to `user_id` and added table name.

Comment: @DipeshParmar do you realize that `%H` displays number of hours? If you want complete time (in seconds) skip `time format` and `sec to time`. If you want full time use: `%H:%m:%s`.

Comment: `time_to_sec(<value>)/3600` is a very hand method of getting "total hours" for use as a scalar or float.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this, it will give you the total no of hours:

**For Example:**

```
SELECT sum(time_to_sec(timediff(end, start ))/ 3600) AS 'totalHour' from test;
```

If you run this query for above table you given, it shows the output `4.5` hours.

Hope it will help you.

Comment: yes its returning `4.5000` but it should be `06:30:00` as pre record shown in my question.

Comment: @DipeshParmar as i can see you want the total of each day difference in time so, so for your data it should be 4.5 not 6.5.

Answer (score 1):

I already answered in other thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44560345/query-is-not-working/44567322#44567322

I just created a temporary table called dataimport

[Table Format][1]

and wrote a query as,

```sql
SELECT `EnNo`, work_dt,
        SEC_TO_TIME(sum(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,login,logout))) as time_worked 
from (
    SELECT `EnNo`, date(`DateTime`) as work_dt, `DateTime` as login
        , coalesce(
              (SELECT MIN(`DateTime`) 
               FROM `dataimport` as b 
               WHERE a.EnNo = b.EnNo 
                 and date(a.`DateTime`) = date(b.`DateTime`)
                 and b.`DateTime` >= a.`DateTime` 
                 and b.`INOUT` = 'E'
              ), now()) AS logout
    FROM `dataimport` AS a 
    WHERE a.`INOUT` = 'S'
) as t
GROUP BY `EnNo`, work_dt
```

Finally got the output as,

[Output][2]

Hope this is what you are lookin on.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OEEMe.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/g6ivm.png

Answer (score 0):

Change your

```
SELECT HOUR(TIMEDIFF(end,start)) AS 'totalHour'
```

to

```
SELECT sum(TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, end, start)) AS 'totalHour'
```

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT IF(DATE(datetime_end) = DATE(datetime_start), TIMEDIFF(datetime_end,datetime_start), IF(DATEDIFF(datetime_start,datetime_end) > 1, ADDTIME( TIME_FORMAT(CONCAT((DATEDIFF(datetime_start,datetime_end) - 1) * 8,':00:00'), "%H:%i:%s"), ADDTIME( TIMEDIFF(datetime_end,CONCAT(DATE(datetime_end),' 08:00:00')), TIMEDIFF(CONCAT(DATE(datetime_start),' 17:00:00'),datetime_start) ) ) , ADDTIME( TIMEDIFF(datetime_end,CONCAT(DATE(datetime_end),' 08:00:00')), TIMEDIFF(CONCAT(DATE(datetime_start),' 17:00:00'),datetime_start) ) ) ) AS total_working_hrs FROM table`